# Why does multithreaded execution not work when the subroutine is expensive?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, rust

This program randomly prints the index number such as 1, 4, 2, 3, 100 ....

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    for x in 0..100 {
        print!("{}: {:?} ", x, child.join());
    }
}
```

However, once I add the `ping()` function, which does something other than console output, it no longer executes concurrently, instead just iterating the `ping()` function.

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate reqwest;

use reqwest::Client;
use std::thread;
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    for x in 0..100 {
        let child = thread::spawn(move || {
            ping(x);
        });
        print!("{}: {:?} ", x, child.join());
    }
}

fn ping(x: i32) {
    let output = if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
                    Command::new("cmd")
                        .args(&["/C", "echo hello"])
                        .output()
                        .expect("failed to execute process")
                 } else {
                     Command::new("sh")
                         .arg("-c")
                         .arg("https://keisugano.blogspot.com/")
                         .output()
                         .expect("failed to execute process")
                 };
    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

What is the root cause of this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The first example is incomplete without actually spawning threads, so not sure what happened there.

The key point here is that `join` is blocking, meaning it won't return until the underlying thread is completed. From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join):

> `pub fn join(self) -> Result<T>`
>
> Waits for the associated thread to finish.
>
> In terms of atomic memory orderings, the completion of the associated thread synchronizes with this function returning. In other words, all operations performed by that thread are ordered before all operations that happen after join returns.

With this new knowledge, it is clear that what your code actually did was: create a new thread, wait for it to its completion, and then create the next one. So it is still sequntial and clearly not what you intended.

The solution is straightforward: create all the threads first, then wait them to finish as showed below:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let handles = (0..100)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| {
            thread::spawn(move || {
                ping(x);
            })
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    for thread in handles {
        thread.join().unwrap();
    }
}

fn ping(x: i32) {
    // Do things.
}
```

Comment: It worked! thanks ;)